# jQuery Bootstrap & LocalStorage how to remember icon state of GlyphIcons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pivi/ed0d7oLo/7/

1. Menu is generated dynamically from database (in case someone wonders why my icons are not hard-coded)
2. I am using Bootstrap Collapse and Glyphicons
3. I am looping trough the panels, find the ones which are top level, assign icon to them..and toggle the panels (open/collapsed) icons with css
4. Furthermore, **i am using LocalStorage** to remember/restore the panel(s) state.

For panels, LocalStorage works fine.. but

*** Question: How do i loop trough the icons state and set LocalStorage?
The (open/collapsed) state gets lost when re-visiting or refreshing the page***

A possible solution would be to loop trough the icons state, get the state and then toggle them like:

```
//Get the state
var activePanel = localStorage.getItem('activePanel');
[...stuff for LocalStorage...]

//Then
$('a[aria-controls="' + activePanel + '"]')
    .removeClass('collapsed')
    .attr('aria-expanded', true)
    .find('whatever').toggleClass('glyphicon-a-sign glyphicon-b-sign');

$('#' + activePanel).addClass('in');
```

But this is not possible since i am switching the icons with css

Idea? ;-)

Comment: I solved the issue for time being with pure CSS and a function to add a dummy class since [aria-expanded="true"] at h4 is only available on click
New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pivi/1bjo190r/3/    
-----
However, any other solutions are welcome